# Different or Same Face detection using objective c

Tags: objective-c

How can I detect different or same face is detected?How can I identify face is the different or same person using objective c?Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-iOS can help you. It includes this exact task as an example.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AVFoundation for your job.

In particular AvCaptureMetadataOutput to manage metadata founded in the frame captured